# Best practice for where to place Services folder in C# Blazor Web Assembly (ASP.NET Core hosted) application?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

Where is the best place to create a Services folder in a C# Blazor Web Assembly (ASP.NET Core hosted) application? A Web Assembly (ASP.NET Core hosted) application has 3 projects for 1. Client, 2. Server and 3. Shared.

My initial thought is to place the Services folder in the root of the Shared project. Is there a best practice of where the Services folder should be placed for this kind of application, maybe in the Server project for example?

I have created a Service to read a CSV file which I have registered with the Dependency Injection service to make it easier to access throughout the project and also for testing. I will be adding other services as well so would be good to know if anyone else has a preferred place to add those services normally?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand what is sent to the browser and what is kept on the server-side. The Client project has reference to the Shared project (by default), so once compiled both projects Client and Shared will be sent to the browser (as .dll). The Shared project is also referenced by the Server project, and it acts like a "bridge", holds some common constructs. Having that said, I'd suggest you do the following:

- Client project - You place all your client-side logic, your razor components, your views, and the code that calls various API endpoints (or it might be gRPC calls).
- Server project - Here you keep all your API endpoints and back-end services.
- Shared project - Since this is referenced by both, a copy is sent to browser, and another one kept as part of your server application. This is a good place to put all your Dto models. Avoid placing any services or any logic-related constructs. The common constructs between Client and Server are the models only. Having a shared project is just a convenience, you can of course opt it out completely, and duplicate your models in both places.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense :)

Comment: Highly Highly underrated answer / question. Been searching for hours to find a clear explanation for what the three projects are for.. thank you